# mapper and reducer code incorrect

Tags: python, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

Mapper code :-

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    data = line.strip().split("\t")
    if len(data) == 6:
        date, time, place, temp, pressure, humidity = data
        print "{0}\t{1}".format(place, temp)
```

reducer code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

max_val = -sys.maxfloat
oldKey = None


for line in sys.stdin:
    data_mapped = line.strip().split("\t")
    if len(data_mapped) != 2:
        # Something has gone wrong. Skip this line.
        continue

    thisKey, thisVal = data_mapped

    if oldKey and oldKey != thisKey:
        print oldKey, "\t", max_val

        (oldKey, max_val) = (thisKey, float(thisVal))   
    else:
    (oldKey, max_val) = (thisKey, max(max_val, float(thisVal)))

if oldKey != None:
    print oldKey, "\t", max_val
```

---

the reducer code is not running i try everything
the mapper is ruunung correctly but not reducer

---

my dataset is like this:

```
2012-01-01  09:00   San Jose    28  214.05  25
2012-01-01  09:00   Fort Worth  19  153.57  32
2012-01-01  09:00   San Diego   0   66.08   35
2012-01-01  09:00   Pittsburgh  18  493.51  28
2012-01-01  09:00   Omaha   10  235.63  32
2012-01-01  09:00   Stockton    28  247.18  32
2012-01-01  09:00   Austin  44  379.6   32
2012-01-01  09:00   New York    26  296.8   35
2012-01-01  09:00   Corpus Christi  32  25.38   28
2012-01-01  09:00   Fort Worth  32  213.88  32
2012-01-01  09:00   Las Vegas   21  53.26   32
2012-01-01  09:00   Newark  21  39.75   35
2012-01-01  09:00   Austin  44  469.63  32
2012-01-01  09:00   Greensboro  32  290.82  32
2012-01-01  09:00   San Francisco   0   260.65  28
2012-01-01  09:00   Lincoln 33  136.9   32
2012-01-01  09:00   Buffalo 19  483.82  32
2012-01-01  09:00   San Jose    19  215.82  35
2012-01-01  09:00   Boston  44  418.94  25
```

first their is date , time, place, temp, pressure, humidity

Comment: how to make it correct that what i m asking

Comment: Python uses _INDENTATION:_ to declare scopes. Please fix your code so it is euqal to what you have.

Comment: sorry i dont have much knowledge about it can u tell me how to do it

Comment: I have no clue what you want to achieve. your "mapper code"  reads in no data. I guess you read in somehow your table below. It then prints only `place` and `temp` from it. your reduce code would reduce multiple lines of the same `place` and only print the `place` and its highest `temp`

Comment: i want to get max. temperature. each city have some different temperature in different time so i want to know what is the max temp of particular city of all the time.